# Complicated Declaration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, declaration

How do we interpret the following declaration:

```
char (*(*f())[])();
```

How shall one develop a handy technique to read such complicated or even more complicated declarations in C. If you use a quick trick, please share.

Comment: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: Is this homework, or is some big company laying off staff and this is the test? I swear that the exact same question has been asked just hours ago...

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com) is very helpful for checking yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations gives a good tutorial.

Comment: I get a 404. Anybody have a cached copy?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a not-so-well-known trick. Pretend that `f` is a variable name, and that `*`, `()` and `[]` are operations you can do on it. Use the precedence rules of C operators to wit that:

```
f
```

can be applied

```
f()
```

and then dereferenced

```
*f()
```

and then subscripted

```
(*f())[]
```

and then dereferenced

```
*(*f())[]
```

and then applied

```
(*(*f())[])()
```

to give a `char`

```
char (*(*f())[])()
```

so `f` is a function returning a pointer to an array of pointers to functions returning char.